# Named capture group doesn't work with dynamic regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've a regex that is being built dynamically:

```
permitted_keys = %w[attachment avatar banner document]

# my actual key
key = 'banner_content_type'

# g1 will be the captured grouped or nil
/(?<g1>#{permitted_keys.join('|')})_content_type/ =~ key

p "g1 #{g1.inspect}"
```

The problem is that building this regex dynamically I'm getting the following error:

> NameError (undefined local variable or method `g1' for...

However, if I put the values in regex statically, like this:

```
/(?<g1>attachment|avatar|banner|document)_content_type/ =~ key
```

It completely works.

What's the problem with the first approach? TIA.

PS:

I've already compared the following in terminal:

```
/(?<g1>#{permitted_keys.join('|')})_content_type/ == 
/(?<g1>attachment|avatar|banner|document)_content_type/
```

... and it returns `true`.

You can check the examples in the following links:

[Example 1](https://repl.it/KrrD/0)

[Example 2](https://repl.it/KrrD/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the first approach is that using string interpolation in the regex literal disables the assignment of the local variables. From [`Regexp#=~`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Regexp.html#method-i-3D-7E):

> If `=~` is used with a regexp literal with named captures, captured strings (or `nil`) is assigned to local variables named by the capture names.
>
> ... snipped...
>
> This assignment is implemented in the Ruby parser. The parser detects ‘regexp-literal =~ expression’ for the assignment. **The regexp must be a literal without interpolation** and placed at left hand side.
>
> ... snipped ...
>
> A regexp interpolation, `#{}`, also disables the assignment.

You can always just use [`Regexp#match`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Regexp.html#method-i-match) to get the captures, but I'm not sure of anyway to automatically assign local variables like this (honestly I didn't know `=~` would do so):

```
match_data = /(?<g1>#{permitted_keys.join('|')})_content_type/.match(key)
match_data['g1']
# => "banner"
```

or if you like dealing with globals:

```
/(?<g1>#{permitted_keys.join('|')})_content_type/ =~ key
$~['g1']
# => "banner"
```

Comment: Thanks for the very helpful answer :)